# Datatable.rows.add is overwriting the same row

Tags: asp.net, datatable

We are reading rows of one table in a loop and getting a column value in a datarow and using Datatable.rows.add(datarow) method adding the row into a new databale2.

But the data is getting overwritten in one single row in datatable2.

Comment: Post some code in Your question, please.

Comment: pretty sure it will be that your using the same instance of datarow without creating a new one